# Is this a right way to assign setID to edittext in android programming

Tags: android

i have a array suppose int Array[]= new array[50];
and i want to assign an array to edittext field setid like this

edittext.setId(array[]);

is this possible
what i want to do is that

edittext suppose ed1 should have id as array[0]
edittext suppose ed2 should have id as array[1]
and so on . .

please help!

Comment: If you dynamically create EditText then you need to define editText.setId.

Comment: How do you define the textviews ? by programatically or statically ?

Comment: textview= new textview